# Converting to "set-option" SMTLib format

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to convert this z3py code ([online code](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/gZslh)) to standard SMTLib format. Everything is converted to SMTLib format except the set options properties  "**(set-option :produce-models true) (set-option :timeout 4000)"**. Why isn't working? The conversion code was suggested by Leonardo de Moura.

I want output to be like -

```
; benchmark 
(set-info :status unknown)
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :timeout 4000)
(set-logic QF_UFLIA)
(assert true)
(check-sat)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Options are not printed by the SMT-LIB2 pretty printer. 
The pretty printer returns a string and you 
should be able to pre-pend options of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Is this the right way to define set option for solver. "s = Solver(); s.set(unsat_core=True)
s.set(models = True);
s.set(timeout = 4000)" Because if I set any arbitrary keyword then z3py don't provide any error. Is there any documentation for the keywords that it support?

Answer (score 0):

I am running your code and  I am obtaining

```
; benchmark
(set-info :status unknown)
(set-logic QF_UFLIA)
(assert true)
(check-sat)
```